# Como indexar no google sites que usam javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, seo

Estou fazendo um site SPA com angularJS e estou enfrentando dificuldades em indexar todas as páginas no google, pois como carrego as informações via AJAX, ele só indexa a minha página inicial, eu já li muitas coisas a respeito, e eu tenho um bom inglês, mas resolvi vir aqui procurar por ajuda por alguém que falasse de maneira mais clara pra mim. Eu li algo sobre `hashbangs(#!)` e `_escaped_fragment_` e até entendi, porém não sei como lidar com essa parada de `_escaped_fragment_` e criar `snapshots`, se alguém pudesse me explicar melhor ficaria grato.

Answer (score 1):

Realmente indexar conteúdo em Ajax dá muita 'dor de cabeça', após muitos meses pesquisando encontrei algumas maneiras, ainda estou no processo de testes, mas, já estou vendo bons resultados... você pode estar fazendo o seguinte:

O Google disponibiliza algumas ferramentas que faz a indexação de conteúdo em Ajax/ javascript/ SEO Angular etc.. Eu fiz esse processo e as url's, títulos e descrições apareceram no mecanismo de buscas/pesquisas do google.

Acesse:  https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/googlebot-fetch?hl=
Adicione um site, em seguida vá em `rastreamento` > `Buscar como o Google` e insira as páginas que quer renderizar e depois indexar.  Existe muitas outras ferramentas excelentes nesse site para nós auxiliar, vale a pena estudá-las.

Mais informações: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6066467?hl=pt-BR

Yannick do SEO4Ajax  disponibilizou esses módulos para .htaccess e as redes sociais funcionaram: Substitua **yousite** com o nome do seu domínio, substitua **put you token**  pelo seu token (para conseguir o token cadastre-se no site: seo4ajax.com) depois copie e cole no seu .htaccess.

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
RequestHeader set Host "api.seo4ajax.com"
</IfModule>

<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
Options +FollowSymLinks
# Redirect yousite.com to www.yousite.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yousite\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.yousite.com/$1 [L,R=301]

<IfModule mod_proxy_http.c>
# If requested with the _escaped_fragment_ query parameter, proxify
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !(index.html) [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _escaped_fragment_= [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [E=PROXIFY:true]

# If requested by a bot that does not support the specification, proxify
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !(index.html) [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  !(google.*bot|bing|msnbot|yandexbot|pinterest.*ios|mail\.ru) [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  (bot|crawler|spider|archiver|pinterest|facebookexternalhit|flipboardproxy) [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [E=PROXIFY:true]

# Proxification to SEO4Ajax
RequestHeader set Host "api.seo4ajax.com" env=PROXIFY
RewriteCond  %{ENV:PROXIFY}  true
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ <http://api.seo4ajax.com/put you token/$1> [P,QSA,L]
</ifModule>
# html5 pushstate enable
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
</ifModule>
```

Passe as informações do seu array para os schemas e meta property;
Coloque esses schemas e as meta property nas suas views.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in grupo">
   <!-- Schemas -->
   <div span itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article"></span>
   <span itemprop="name" content="{{item.title}}"></span>

   <span itemprop="description" content="{{item.description}}"></span>

   <span itemprop="articleSection" content="Humor"></span>

   <span itemprop="image" content="http://www.yousite.com/images/{{item.img}}" ></span>
   </div>
   <!-- End - Schemas -->

   <!-- Meta property  -->
  <meta property="og:title" content="{{item.title}}" />
  <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.yousite.com/images/{{item.img}}" />
  <meta property="og:description" content="{{item.description}}" />
  <!-- End - Meta property  -->
</div>
```

Após o SEO4Ajax fazer a captura das páginas do seu site, você pode fazer o donwload do sitemap, enviar para o gerenciador de arquivos, de onde você hospeda seu site, e adicioná-lo no Ferramentas para webmasters do google, isso ajuda também.

Qualquer dúvida pode estar perguntando, se eu souber estarei ajudando, valeu!

Answer (score 0):

O [Google já lê Javascript](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.no/2014/05/understanding-web-pages-better.html) e se fores ao teu [Google Webmaster Tool](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home) podes perceber melhor como isso funciona :)