# Quais as implicações de carregar o conteúdo de um aplicação web depois do carregamento principal?

Tags: aplicação-web, seo

Estou pensando em criar uma página institucional (que geralmente é estática) dinâmica, onde os textos são salvos no banco e podem ser alterados por um administrador. Logo, meu `index.html` seria apenas algumas metas tags, uma imagem (ou CSS) de loading e um *script* que carregaria o layout e textos

A pergunta é, do ponto de vista de SEO, posso ser afetado negativamente? Por exemplo, o robô do Google, quando passar pelo meu site, não esperar e ler uma página praticamente vazia

Se tiver outros problemas que eu possa ter que resolver nesse caso, seria útil saber

Observação: nesse caso não é possível carregar o layout e textos do lado do servidor e já retornar pro cliente a página pronta

Comment: Não entendi o que vc quis dizer na *observação*, na verdade ficou meio ambíguo.... Pelo que vc me descreveu o que vc quer fazer é bem próximo do que é hoje o WordPress. Ele é mentado no back, tem uma área de adm onde se fazem os textos etc, e ele é muito bem indexado pelo Goolge...

Comment: Não conheço o WP muito bem, sei que muita coisa é dinâmica, mas não sabia se ele renderizava o HTML no back ou no front. É que no caso eu usaria o Firebase, então não teria um servidor

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss ficou mas claro agora. Guilherme sem o servidor realmenão sei dizer. Mas o bot do Google entende bm páginas dinâmicas, inclusive que usam PHP/Angular/React etc... Talvez isso https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/298009/react-afeta-o-seo é isso https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/59095/como-indexar-no-google-sites-que-usam-javascript/ possam te interessar.

Comment: Provavelmente dup desta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/77808/101. E ainda complementa: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/354818/101 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/68286/101 Lá eu falo do mito que página com interações vão ser bem indexadas pelo Google

Comment: Talvez seja duplicata mesmo, mas no caso dessas seriam SPAs que possuem múltiplas páginas, no meu caso eu só tenho uma página, afinal é um site institucional. Valeu pelos links